# Does the "low word" and "high word" locations of a WParam change in 64bit code?

Tags: delphi, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to handle the WM_XBUTTONUP message which is from the extra mouse buttons on some mice.  The SDK documentation states that the low word of wParam holds the virtual key information and that the high word holds which button was pressed.  I understand how this works in 32bit code, however in 64bit code the wParam is a 64bit unsigned integer.  I've seen code that uses Lo(msg.wparam) and Hi(msg.wparam).  Does this code still work in 64bits or does something have to change?  In other words, does the definition of "high word" change from 32bit to 64bit?

Comment: I just wanted to mention that unfortunately I don't have a mouse with the extra buttons to test, otherwise I'd debug the msg to figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any code that uses [`Lo()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Lo) and [`Hi()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Hi) is wrong because those functions return the low and high order bytes of a `Word`.

---

The MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646246.aspx) says the following:

> Use the following code to get the information in the wParam parameter:
>
> ```
> fwKeys = GET_KEYSTATE_WPARAM (wParam); 
> fwButton = GET_XBUTTON_WPARAM (wParam);
> ```

These macros are defined in the header files as:

```
#define GET_KEYSTATE_WPARAM(wParam)     (LOWORD(wParam))
#define GET_XBUTTON_WPARAM(wParam)      (HIWORD(wParam))
```

In turn, `LOWORD` and `HIWORD` are defined as follows:

```
#define LOWORD(_dw)     ((WORD)(((DWORD_PTR)(_dw)) & 0xffff))
#define HIWORD(_dw)     ((WORD)((((DWORD_PTR)(_dw)) >> 16) & 0xffff))
```

These macros are designed to perform the correct task when compiled into both 32 bit and 64 bit code.

In Delphi, the `Windows` unit contains translations of `LoWord` and `HiWord` that perform the same tasks, albeit implemented in a somewhat different manner. So I would implement the following functions:

```
function GET_KEYSTATE_WPARAM(wParam: WPARAM): Word; inline;
function GET_XBUTTON_WPARAM(wParam: WPARAM): Word; inline;

....

function GET_KEYSTATE_WPARAM(wParam: WPARAM): Word;
begin
  Result := LoWord(wParam);
end;

function GET_XBUTTON_WPARAM(wParam: WPARAM): Word;
begin
  Result := HiWord(wParam);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Does it seem odd that the "high word" of a 64bit value is handled the same as a 32bit value?  It seems that it should be >> 32 instead of >> 16?  Or am I just thinking of it incorrectly?

Comment: FYI, if you are using a `TMessage` based handler to receive the message, `TMessage` already has its own `WParamLo/Hi` and `LParamLo/Hi` members to separate the values for you, and they work just fine in 64bit.

Comment: `>> 48` would give you the high word of a 64 bit integer. What's really happening here with `HiWord` is that it is getting the second word of the four.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, David.  I think it's just that I was thinking that "high word" is a bit ambiguous in the 64bit case.

Comment: @MarkF Indeed it is. It's the high word of the low dword, if that makes sense! Remember that all this started in 32 bit days.

Comment: That's what I was missing... Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You should have shown the code. `Lo` and `Hi` return the low byte and the high byte of a 16-bit value, respectively, so they wouldn't work with 32-bit code, either. Perhaps you meant `LoWord` and `HiWord`.

In 64-bit code, you can typecast a 64-bit integer value to [`Int64Rec`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.SysUtils.Int64Rec):

`case Int64Rec(Msg.WParam).Lo of` ...

Comment: `Int64Rec(Msg.WParam)` can only compile for 64 bit targets. You'd need conditional code to compile for 32 bit targets.